# Empty value for int property

Tags: javascript

I got the following class:

```
function Corpus(name){

    this.name=name; // A string
    this.recordings = []; // An array to fill
    this.num = ... ; // A int number to set later

}
```

What is the best default value for my int value (num), when it is not defined ?

Comment: I think it should start off at 9.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering for a standard for this type a problem. But thanks for the "9" suggestion anyway !

Comment: I'd go for [**42**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29)

Comment: Funny ! Who's next ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you want to do with it. It's perfectly fine to leave it `undefined`, to set it to `false`, and if you plan to do some math with it, you can always set it to zero (`0`).

Note that all of the above values are falsy, so the loose typing in JS make it matter even less.

---

If you want to easily check whether it's been defined or not, then leave it `undefined` or `false`, but don't forget to compare by value AND type later to avoid errors:

```
this.num = false;

this.num ==  0; // true  - be careful with this
this.num === 0; // false - the way to go
```

Comment: do you mean this.num=false ?

Comment: Yes, or just leave it out (it will revert to undefined), or simply `this.num = 0;`

Comment: Thanks ! Is false better than null ?

Comment: No, they are the same in your case. The difference might be a tiny fragment of a microsecond in the code execution. :)

Answer (score 3):

The best value candidate for a number is 0, so that the typed is predefined, but the value unknown.

This is because JavaScript has internal types, even though it seems weakly typed at our level.

More generally for different types:

- String: `''`
- Object: `null`
- Array: `null`
- RegExp: `null`

---

As a side note, it is totally legit to leave it undefined as said in  [Shomz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965907/shomz)'s answer of your question. It is up to you from here :)

Comment: Always nice to see an answer saying what I said 3 minutes ago getting upvoted. :D

Comment: so your answer is this.num=0 ? Ok. However 0 could be one of my values, so this is not a good choice for me if I want to test if this value of num is already set.

Comment: @Shomz Dude, I always try to give the credits to people who deserve it in my answers, my answer is different from yours though if you read it.

Comment: Haha, thank you for the credit, I was just commenting how things on SO work. :) I gave you an upvote.

Comment: @sandoval31 Yes that is what I mean, but feel whatever suits your needs the best

Comment: I'm just curious, how `0` would be "unknown", it is a very exact value.

Comment: @Teemu it sounds right, but there are examples where it sounds true (i.e. calculating a total for an unsigned number)

Comment: numbers?, Could add an empty number as well?